# Difference between var arg and array

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions, javap

Suppose I have a code like

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static String method1(String[] array){return ""+array.length;}
    public static String method2(String... array){return ""+array.length;}


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(method1(new String[]{"test"})); //allowed
        //System.out.println(method1("test")); Not allowed
        System.out.println(method2(new String[]{"test"}));  //allowed
        System.out.println(method2("test")); //allowed
    }
}
```

When I do `javap HelloWorld`

```
C:\Users\athakur\JavaProjectWorkspace\HelloWorld\bin\test>javap HelloWorld
Compiled from "HelloWorld.java"
public class test.HelloWorld extends java.lang.Object{
    public test.HelloWorld();
    public static java.lang.String method1(java.lang.String[]);
    public static java.lang.String method2(java.lang.String[]);
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

So as per the class file method1 and method2 take same array argument. Then why the difference in the input they can take?

Like method1 cannot take simple String input where as var arg can take variable String inputs as well as array?

Comment: @Downvoter could you please provide reason for your downvote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So as per the class file method1 and method2 take same array argument.

Yes, except there's extra metadata within the class file to indicate that the parameter for `method2` is a varargs parameter. It's really just an extra bit of data on the parameter - that's all.

You can detect it with reflection using [`Parameter.isVarArgs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#isVarArgs--).

All it means is that the compiler is willing to take a call like this:

```
method2("test")
```

and implicitly convert it into

```
method2(new String[] { "test" })
```

You don't *always* want that behaviour, so it has to be explicitly specified on the parameter using the varargs syntax.

I suspect you're also using a slightly old version of `javap`, if it's not showing you the difference between the two method declarations. On my version (Java 8) I get:

```
public static java.lang.String method1(java.lang.String[]);
public static java.lang.String method2(java.lang.String...);
```

Comment: Yeah i am using Java 7. Should try it out wit 8 sometime. Tx!

Comment: @Jon Skeet you are such a guru, where ever I see a post from him I get to learn something new.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is signature of a method that might have a variable  number of arguments, as opposed to an array argument you can pass only one argument. Anyway passing array to a method as vararg is accepted and will be used internally. On the other hand vararg arguments will be converted to an array and used there.

When you pass an array as argument to both method works. To answer you question lets don't use an array

```
System.out.println(method2("test")); //allowed
System.out.println(method2("test","test2")); //allowed
```

This works only if you use vararg argument, as you have noticed.